# Android 10: Able to upload a Uri directly but fails with "Permission denial" exception when re-attempted later

Tags: android, permission-denied, android-10.0, android-securityexception

Using a FilePicker I am able to have the user choose a file to upload, pass it to an IntentService, and upload it immediately via that intentService if device has network.
But if there is no network, I need to save the Uri and attempt upload later once the devices gets network. This re-attempt is failing. It throws "Permission denial" exception when I try to start the service during the re-attempt. Please let me know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
FILEPICKER
-----------
openFilePickDialog = new Intent();
openFilePickDialog.setType("*/*");
openFilePickDialog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openFilePickDialog, "Select File"), PickFileId);

During re-attempt of upload
----------------------------
Intent iUploadService = new Intent(context, UploadService.class);
String uriString = pendingUpload.uriString;
iUploadService.setData(Uri.parse(uriString));
iUploadService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
iUploadService.putExtra(UploadService.ACTION, UploadService.ACTION_UPLOAD);
context.startService(iUploadService);

Stacktrace
-----------
java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10140 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.aaaa.bbbb%2Ffiles%2FFolder%2FAttachments%2F1587129056397_IMG-20200414-WA0004.jpg [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startService(IActivityManager.java:5166)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1601)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1571)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:669)
```

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Thanks, let me try this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use ACTION_GET_CONTENT as as you have seen the permission to read does not live long.

Instead use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and take persistable uri permission in onActivityResult.

Comment: Perfect. I added takePersistableUriPermission call in the onResult callback and I could do this - a) Turn off net and attempt upload b) Switch off the device c) Turn it on and when upload resumed, upload it. Thank you !