# Android 10: Unable to access later an image that can chosen through Photos/Gallery

Tags: file-permissions, android-10.0

This is a variation of the question I had asked the other day and resolved with help.

[Android 10: Able to upload a Uri directly but fails with "Permission denial" exception when re-attempted later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318414/android-10-able-to-upload-a-uri-directly-but-fails-with-permission-denial-exc)

Using a combination of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission, I am able to upload later a file that was chosen by user.

But, if the user selects an image through Photos/Gallery to share through our app and if there is no network at that moment, as expected the app needs to attempt the upload later. During this re-attempt, I am facing a "Permission Denial" exception. Please let me know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

How the URI is retrieved

```
callingIntent = new SharedIntent();
callingIntent.action = getIntent().getAction();
callingIntent.type = getIntent().getType();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(callingIntent.action) ||
    Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(callingIntent.action))
{
    callingIntent.uri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (null == callingIntent.uri)
        callingIntent.uri = getIntent().getData();
    callingIntent.aUri = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
}
```

In the Intent that receives the URI through Photos, we have this -

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(callingIntent.uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

To call the the IntentService to which the URI is passed for upload -

```
intentService.setData(callingIntent.uri);
intentService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startService(intentService);
```

But when the startService is called, there is a "Permission denial" exception - "Permission denial: no permissions found for UID...."

Comment: "if the user selects an image through Photos/Gallery to share through our app" -- your [mcve] does not really show this. Where is the `uri` coming from, exactly?

Comment: I have updated the question with that URI retrieval snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reliably get persistable `Uri` permissions on arbitrary `Uri` values. That only works if you get the `Uri` from the Storage Access Framework, such as your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` scenario. A `Uri` that you receive from `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` is unlikely to have been obtained from the Storage Access Framework.

As a result, you have to use that `Uri` immediately. If you cannot do so, your options are:

1. Tell the user that you cannot perform their desired operation now, or
2. Make a local copy of the data now to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) while you can, then use and delete the copy later

Comment: Our app feature requires that we try the upload later when user gets network, so the only option is to create a copy and delete after upload I guess. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @KrishnanVS: You may still want to pop up a dialog or something and ask the user if that is what they want. If the content is large, making the copy might consume more storage space than they would like.

Comment: Sure, I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any attribute in the uri that will tell us if it is shared from Storage Access Framework or if it is an arbitrary uri ?

Comment: @KrishnanVS: You can try [`isDocumentUri()` on `DocumentsContract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract?hl=en#isDocumentUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)). I have not used it, but it seems like it should meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, will check.

Comment: I implemented it another way - if upload fails, then check if the Uri allows persistable permission. If not, then save a copy for later.